# Bar Chart with Different Widths and Colors in matplotlib (Bar Mekko chart)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create what is known as [bar mekko chart](https://www.mekkographics.com/resources/charts-by-type/bar-mekko/) in matplotlib.

I found that bar chart in matplotlib can do the trick but I am missing how to show a colorbar with the values centered at 0.

Here is my attempt, commented the snippets I am still missing:

[image: example]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.cm as cm

%matplotlib inline

x = np.array([0.       , 0.4512135, 0.760715 , 0.775948 , 0.977063 , 1.170482 ,
       1.229812 , 1.3009845, 1.347207 , 1.4155705, 1.928897 ])

bin_width = np.diff(x)

y = np.array([ 0.40048296,  1.11131896,  0.30525134,  3.86793415, 21.80974083,
       11.88354534, 13.84599687,  9.7484865 ,  9.5418679 , 22.39983675])
z = np.array([0.       , 0.4512135, -0.760715 , 0.775948 , 0.977063 , 1.170482 ,
       1.229812 , 1.3009845, 1.347207 , -1.4155705])

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1)



#?# offset = mcolors.DivergingNorm(vcenter=0.)
# Colorbar needs to be centered (0 should be yellow always)

colors = plt.cm.RdYlBu(z) # offset???

bar_plot = ax1.bar(x[:-1],y, 
        color=colors, 
        width=bin_width, 
        align='edge')


#?# sm = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(0,max(data_color)))
#?# sm.set_array([])
#?# cbar = plt.colorbar(sm)

plt.ylabel("y")

plt.show()
# plt.colorbar(mappable=bar_plot, ax=ax1) ??
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have found all the bits and pieces necessary and tinkered them together in the wrong way.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.cm as cm


x = np.array([0.       , 0.4512135, 0.760715 , 0.775948 , 0.977063 , 1.170482 ,
       1.229812 , 1.3009845, 1.347207 , 1.4155705, 1.928897 ])

bin_width = np.diff(x)

y = np.array([ 0.40048296,  1.11131896,  0.30525134,  3.86793415, 21.80974083,
       11.88354534, 13.84599687,  9.7484865 ,  9.5418679 , 22.39983675])
z = np.array([0.       , 0.4512135, -0.760715 , 0.775948 , 0.977063 , 1.170482 ,
       1.229812 , 1.3009845, 1.347207 , -1.4155705])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


cmap = plt.cm.RdYlBu
norm = mcolors.DivergingNorm(vmin=z.min(), vcenter=0., vmax=z.max())
sm = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

bar_plot = ax.bar(x[:-1], y,  color=cmap(norm(z)),  width=bin_width,  align='edge')

cbar = fig.colorbar(sm)

ax.set_ylabel("y")

plt.show()
```